# How to open a font file by ShellExecuteEx?

Tags: delphi, windows-shell

I get a font file's absolute PIDL  named  `FontPIDL`

I use this code to open it : 
    var
      ShExeInfo : SHELLEXECUTEINFO;

```
begin
    ZeroMemory(@ShExeInfo, SizeOf(ShExeInfo));

    ShExeInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(ShExeInfo);
    ShExeInfo.lpVerb := 'Open';
    ShExeInfo.lpIDList := FontPIDL;
    ShExeInfo.nShow := SW_SHOWNORMAL;
    ShExeInfo.fMask := SEE_MASK_IDLIST;
end;
```

get a error  : `The parameter is incorrect`

I wonder how to fix it ? is some parameter I miss ?

**Update :**

How I get font file absolute PIDL :

```
var
  psfDeskTop : IShellFolder;
  psfFont : IShellFolder;
  pEnumList : IEnumIdList;
  pidFont : PItemIdList;
  pidChild : PItemIdList;
  pidAbFont : PItemIdList; 
  FontPath : array[0..MAX_PATH - 1] of Char;
  pchEaten, dwAttributes, ItemsFetched : ULONG;

begin
  FillChar(FontPath, sizeof(FontPath), #0);
  SHGetSpecialFolderPath(0, FontPath, CSIDL_FONTS, False);
  SHGetDesktopFolder(psfDeskTop);
  psfDeskTop.ParseDisplayName(0, nil, FontPath, pchEaten, pidFont,
    dwAttributes);
  psfDeskTop.BindToObject(pidFont, nil, IID_IShellFolder, psfFont);
  psfFont.EnumObjects(0, SHCONTF_FOLDERS or SHCONTF_NONFOLDERS or
    SHCONTF_INCLUDEHIDDEN, pEnumList);
  ItemsFetched := 0;
  while pEnumList.Next(1, pidChild, ItemsFetched) = NO_ERROR do
  begin
    pidAbFont := ILCombine(pidFont , pidChild);
    ///... do something
  end;

end;
```

Comment: A font file's absolute PIDL

Comment: It would be so much easier if you included a complete program that we could run.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan What can I do if I fix my own question? delete ?

Comment: You can answer the question yourself.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan and accepted my answer ? I feel it's not good .

Comment: @OmairIqbal I also wondered.

Comment: @ONion No, it's just fine to answer and accept your own question. You solved the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Omitting the `lpVerb` assignment makes the code work:

```
begin
    ZeroMemory(@ShExeInfo, SizeOf(ShExeInfo));
    ShExeInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(ShExeInfo);
    // ShExeInfo.lpVerb := 'Open'; will be fail . 
    // use ShExeInfo.lpVerb := '' or ZeroMemory(@ShExeInfo, SizeOf(ShExeInfo)); before
    ShExeInfo.lpIDList := FontPIDL;
    ShExeInfo.nShow := SW_SHOWNORMAL;
    ShExeInfo.fMask := SEE_MASK_IDLIST;
end;
```

Comment: +1 but you don't need to assign to `lpVerb` at all. The call to `ZeroMemory` took care of that.

Comment: @ONion hey man i comment the //lpVerb := 'Open'; in my sample do you sure my answer is unuseful?

Comment: @David Heffernan , can you see the key of this problem in my sample ? dont attack me bro , i help to him.

Comment: @Mahdi, although your code shows the lpVerb assignment commented out, your code *also* shows much more complicated changes. You've given no indication that the only *necessary* change was to lpVerb. Instead, your answer makes it look like we'd need to add lots of code to convert the PIDL into a path. If that's not what you intended to convey, then you need to explain yourself since your intention is not clear from the code alone.

Answer (score 5):

Remove the `ShExeInfo.lpVerb := 'Open';` statement works, but nobody else has said why it works.  The reason is because font files do not have an `"Open"` verb registered by default.  By leaving the `lpVerb` set to `nil`, you allow `ShellExecuteEx()` to execute the actual default verb for the file type, whatever it happens to be.  According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759784.aspx):

> lpVerb
>
> Type: LPCTSTR
>
> A string, referred to as a verb, that specifies the action to be performed. The set of available verbs depends on the particular file or folder. Generally, the actions available from an object's shortcut menu are available verbs. **This parameter can be NULL, in which case the default verb is used if available. If not, the "open" verb is used. If neither verb is available, the system uses the first verb listed in the registry.**

Answer (score 1):

i made a sample to you:

```
var
    ShExeInfo: TShellExecuteInfo;
    ExecuteFile: string;
begin
    ZeroMemory(@ShExeInfo, SizeOf(ShExeInfo));
    ExecuteFile:='D:\SoftWare\font\BDavat.ttf';
    FillChar(ShExeInfo, SizeOf(ShExeInfo), 0) ;
    ShExeInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(TShellExecuteInfo) ;
    with ShExeInfo do
    begin
      //lpVerb := 'Open';
      fMask := SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
      Wnd := Application.Handle;
      lpFile := PWideChar(ExecuteFile) ;
      nShow := SW_SHOWNORMAL;
    end;
    ShellExecuteEx(@ShExeInfo) ;
end;
```

function for get path of them:

```
uses
  ShlObj, ActiveX;

const
  CSIDL_FLAG_CREATE = $8000;
  CSIDL_ADMINTOOLS = $0030;
  CSIDL_ALTSTARTUP = $001D;
  CSIDL_APPDATA = $001A;
  CSIDL_BITBUCKET = $000A;
  CSIDL_CDBURN_AREA = $003B;
  CSIDL_COMMON_ADMINTOOLS = $002F;
  CSIDL_COMMON_ALTSTARTUP = $001E;
  CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA = $0023;
  CSIDL_COMMON_DESKTOPDIRECTORY = $0019;
  CSIDL_COMMON_DOCUMENTS = $002E;
  CSIDL_COMMON_FAVORITES = $001F;
  CSIDL_COMMON_MUSIC = $0035;
  CSIDL_COMMON_PICTURES = $0036;
  CSIDL_COMMON_PROGRAMS = $0017;
  CSIDL_COMMON_STARTMENU = $0016;
  CSIDL_COMMON_STARTUP = $0018;
  CSIDL_COMMON_TEMPLATES = $002D;
  CSIDL_COMMON_VIDEO = $0037;
  CSIDL_CONTROLS = $0003;
  CSIDL_COOKIES = $0021;
  CSIDL_DESKTOP = $0000;
  CSIDL_DESKTOPDIRECTORY = $0010;
  CSIDL_DRIVES = $0011;
  CSIDL_FAVORITES = $0006;
  CSIDL_FONTS  = $0014;
  CSIDL_HISTORY = $0022;
  CSIDL_INTERNET = $0001;
  CSIDL_INTERNET_CACHE = $0020;
  CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA = $001C;
  CSIDL_MYDOCUMENTS = $000C;
  CSIDL_MYMUSIC = $000D;
  CSIDL_MYPICTURES = $0027;
  CSIDL_MYVIDEO = $000E;
  CSIDL_NETHOOD = $0013;
  CSIDL_NETWORK = $0012;
  CSIDL_PERSONAL = $0005;
  CSIDL_PRINTERS = $0004;
  CSIDL_PRINTHOOD = $001B;
  CSIDL_PROFILE = $0028;
  CSIDL_PROFILES = $003E;
  CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES = $0026;
  CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES_COMMON = $002B;
  CSIDL_PROGRAMS = $0002;
  CSIDL_RECENT = $0008;
  CSIDL_SENDTO = $0009;
  CSIDL_STARTMENU = $000B;
  CSIDL_STARTUP = $0007;
  CSIDL_SYSTEM = $0025;
  CSIDL_TEMPLATES = $0015;
  CSIDL_WINDOWS = $0024;

function GetShellFolder(CSIDL: integer): string;
var
  pidl                   : PItemIdList;
  FolderPath             : string;
  SystemFolder           : Integer;
  Malloc                 : IMalloc;
begin
  Malloc := nil;
  FolderPath := '';
  SHGetMalloc(Malloc);
  if Malloc = nil then
  begin
    Result := FolderPath;
    Exit;
  end;
  try
    SystemFolder := CSIDL;
    if SUCCEEDED(SHGetSpecialFolderLocation(0, SystemFolder, pidl)) then
    begin
      SetLength(FolderPath, max_path);
      if SHGetPathFromIDList(pidl, PChar(FolderPath)) then
      begin
        SetLength(FolderPath, length(PChar(FolderPath)));
      end;
    end;
    Result := FolderPath;
  finally
    Malloc.Free(pidl);
  end;
end;
```

how use :

```
ShowMessage(GetShellFolder(CSIDL_FONTS));
```

test it , i hope help you...

Comment: thx , I know that way can open it , but I don't have font file path  , just absolute PItemIDList  , I use `SHGetPathFromIDList()` can't get it path;

Comment: I add a function for getpath ... see see answer now

Comment: For the life of me, I can't see how this relates to the question

Comment: Your function is show "C:\Windows\Fonts" . thx , but I use `SHGetSpecialFolderPath()` get it , and it not relates to the question

Comment: Also the code, even if it misses the point, is weak. Notice how you pass an uninitialized variable to Malloc.Free for example.

Comment: @David Heffernan what are you think ??! , if you can't answer him why tell me your think , and his question updated 26 min after my answer.  don't try bother me please.

Comment: @MahdiParsa The question concerns calling `ShellExecuteEx` using a PIDL. Your answer uses `SHGetSpecialFolderLocation` which makes no sense. I don't see any `CSIDL` in the question. And why use `SHGetPathFromIDList`? The existence of `SEE_MASK_IDLIST` shows that it is possible to use `ShellExecuteEx` without a path. Just a PIDL is enough. The fact that I did not answer the question does not invalidate my criticism. Why don't you address the substance of my criticism rather than attacking me for not answering?

Comment: If your claim is that the PIDL version of ShellExecuteEx doesn't work, and that we *must* pass path names instead, then you need to *say so*. Otherwise, it looks like you're just trying to side-step the question instead of answering it directly. *Merely* commenting out the lpVerb assignment doesn't tell us anything. Please write sentences explaining why your code is the answer. Code without explanation is a poor answer.

Comment: ["Code without explanation is a poor answer."] tnx for you guide man